# Как выводить рандомную строку?

Tags: java, android

Как выводить рандомную строку после остановки анимации, например? 
На данный момент у меня реализовано так:

```
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        //вывод текст здесь
        String[] texts = {};
        Set<Integer> generated = new HashSet<Integer>();
        Random random = new Random ();
        int pos = random.nextInt(texts.length);

        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView)).setText(texts[pos]);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

    }
});
```

Но проблема в том, что значений в `String[] texts = {раз, два, ......, тысяча};` больше тысячи это во первых, а во вторых хотелось бы хранить все в строках, так как в дальнейшем планируется локализация для разных языков.

---

```
@Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                //вывод текст здесь

                Resources res = getResources();
                String[] planets = res.getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);

                Set<Integer> generated = new HashSet<Integer>();
                Random random = new Random ();
                int pos = random.nextInt(R.array.planets_array);

                ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView)).setText(planets[pos]);



            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        });

    }

    }
```

---

CatLog выдает следующее:

```
-09 23:03:08.846 3579-3579/ru.infernal93.butilochka E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: ru.infernal93.butilochka, PID: 3579
                                                                        java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=4; index=2122146214
                                                                            at ru.infernal93.butilochka.ActivityGame$2.onAnimationEnd(ActivityGame.java:81)
                                                                            at android.view.animation.Animation$3.run(Animation.java:376)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:742)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5527)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)
10-09 23:03:08.848 3579-3579/ru.infernal93.butilochka E/MQSEventManagerDelegate: failed to get MQSService.
```

Comment: конструкцию `(TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView)` настоятельно рекомендуется вынести в поле класса (получить один раз при старте) и в дальнейшем работать с этим полем класса, а не получать каждый раз при выводе текста одно и то же значение. поиск виджета по идентификатору довольно "дорогое" для системы удовольствие, чтобы его вот так дергать при каждом обращении, хотя вам может и кажется, что так короче, быстрее и красивее может быть

Answer (score 8, accepted):

В ресурсах можно хранить [массивы](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray)

```
<resources>
    <string-array name="planets_array">
        <item>Mercury</item>
        <item>Venus</item>
        <item>Earth</item>
        <item>Mars</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

---

```
Resources res = getResources();
String[] planets = res.getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
```

Comment: Скомпелировалось без ошибок, но во время вывода текста белый экран на несколько секунд и выход на главный activity. Измененный код и лог файл вставил в изначальный вопрос

Comment: @АрменМхитарян `int pos = random.nextInt(R.array.planets_array);` <- сделайте как было

Comment: Если сделать как было  int pos = random.nextInt(texts.length); то texts выделяется красным

Comment: @АрменМхитарян конечно выделяется, массив же теперь у вас по другому называется, `planets`, а не `texts`

Comment: Разобрался, проблемах была в размерах TextView